# async await module include axios returns Promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

Here's my code

main.js

```
// main.js

const calc = require('./calc');

const calcInfo = calc.getCalcInfo();
console.log('calcInfo:', calcInfo); // I expect wait until response data
```

and calc.js

```
// calc.js

import axios from 'axios';

const getCalcInfo = async () => {
  let resultData = await axios.post('/api/logis/getCalcInfo', {});
  console.log('getCalcInfo', resultData);
  return resultData;
}

export {
  getCalcInfo,
}
```

result log

```
calcInfo: Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseValue]]: Object
calc.js:6 getCalcInfo {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

I expected log "calcInfo" will show axios responsed data. but that's return Promise.

Is there a solution for this issue?

---

EDIT:
thanks for reply!
but i'm still have a question.

this is a modified code.
same main.js and calc.js

```
const getCalcInfo = () => {
  axios.post('/api/logis/getCalcInfo', {})
  .then((result) => {
    return result;
  });
}
```

result here:

```
calcInfo: undefined
```

so I'm not using async(but axios maybe using).
but call getCalcInfo's result is undefined.

why does it work like this?

Comment: It's `await calc.getCalcInfo();`

Comment: Yup, like the comment above said, you need to `await` since you are calling an `async` function which returns a `Promise`

Comment: Do `resultData.data`

Comment: An `async` function _always_ returns a Promise. If you write `return 3` at the end, it won't return the number 3, but a _Promise resolving with the number 3_. That's why you need to await it : `const calcInfo = calc.getCalcInfo()` will be a pending promise, but `const calcInfo = await calc.getCalcInfo()` will be `3`.

Comment: Write a new question if you have another problem. That one should remain closed as a duplicate.